# What makes an English word, an English word?

Tags: dictionaries

There are many new words being added to the dictionary at all times. These include "twerking" or "Google" but who decides if it should be in the dictionary and be an English word?

Here is my theory. One super big company like Oxford, decides that this particular word should be added. Then many other companies just copy them like sheep?

Show what really makes an English word an English word?

Comment: What words get added to the dictionary is beside the point. The OED are only documentarists: they decide what *is important enough* to add, from the activity of usage *which is already happening*. By analogy, political polls don't decide who people are going to vote for (they attempt to discover who people are going to vote for them) --- though in each case, what the polls report and what the dictionaries report can and will affect future behviour of the phenomenon they are reporting.

Comment: [Creating a new word](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/12580/) ◊ [Who decides if a word is “proper” English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/18711/) ◊ [Is there an 'official' way to suggest a new word become part of the English language?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/25138/) ◊ [What are the criteria to adopt new words into English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/11455/) ◊ [When does a word become a word?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/15099/) ◊ The canonical question: [Regulatory bodies and authoritative dictionaries for English](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/462/).

Comment: Oh, and the canonical answer: ["If you use the word when speaking English, then it is an English word."](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/1991/300)

Comment: @RegDwigнt Thank you for closing this question and linking me to some related questions. I have asked this question only because nothing came up as I was typing the question.

Comment: Yes, the algorithm easily fails on this one because, as you can see, different people word the question in very different ways.

Answer (score 1):

This video might help: http://www.merriam-webster.com/video/0031-newwords.htm

I agree. Sometimes it does seem as though a group of five people decide which words become official. :-)